# List pci lanes differentiated by DMI lanes vs directly attached CPU lanes

Tags: pci

Is there a way to list PCI slots (or their respective devices) and output if that slot is directly connected to the CPU, or goes through the southbridge/PCH?

Comment: Seems my question is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1375202/how-to-understand-lspci-tree-format

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to list PCI slots

Yes, you may look into `lspci`

```
man lspci
```

You can see what bridge is used. 
You have different verbose options: 
`lspci -vvv` being the most verbose mode.

You might also get what you want with :

```
hwinfo --short
```

Finally, you can list your slots with `dmidecode -t 9`

And list the on board devices with `dmidecode -t 10`

Comment: I also hoped `lspci` would show me the bridge, but I can't find it anywhere while I list it. Do you happen to have example output which shows the difference between a device connected to the PCH and a device connected to the CPU?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with  _a device connected to the CPU_. The CPU is connected to the motherboard. So it is listed as a "device" itself.

Comment: Well I hoped this clear distinction was made clear in the Question; In the context of pci-express lanes, devices can be directly connected to the CPU, without there being a southbridge/PCH in the communication path. On (intel) consumer platforms it is common that the x16 PCI-e slot is directly connected to the motherboard. Whereas the rest of PCI-e slots are connected to the PCH, which in turn has a DMI conection to the CPU. The DMI connection can be seen as a, often, x4 PCI-e connection. In the case of server platforms, it depends on the vendor how they distribute slots

Answer (score 0):

```
lspci -tv
```

in this example, devices before 0x14 are connected to the CPU root complex.  At or after 0x14 are behind the PCH.

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
       +-01.0-[01]----00.0  Intel Corporation Express Flash NVMe P4500/P4600
       +-14.0  Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
       +-16.0  Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
       +-16.1  Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #2
       +-1a.0  Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
       +-1c.0-[02]--
       +-1c.2-[03]----00.0  Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       +-1c.3-[04]----00.0  Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       +-1c.7-[05-06]----00.0-[06]----00.0  ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family
       +-1d.0  Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
       +-1f.0  Intel Corporation C224 Series Chipset Family Server Standard SKU LPC Controller
       +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
       \-1f.3  Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
```